# Django Template rendering from for loop

Tags: django, templates, jinja2

I have a simple form with a field names as company_name, location, country and few more which I am rendering from views.py as `{'form':form}`.

The usual way to call the form on the template is `{% for field in form %}` which is rendering the fields in the order of field attribute in the form.py file. Another way to add special classes and styles to each field I am calling every field with name as `{{ form.company_name }}`.

I have a another for loop which only contains the names of the form fields `{% for element in fieldnames %}`.

I want to render the form field as per the order in the fieldnames. I tried allot with the below example but not working.

```
{% for element in fieldnames %}
{{ form.element }}
{% endfor %}
```

Why cant we render like above using for loop but if I replace element name with the field name like `{{ form.company_name }}` its working

Comment: because you're wrong. the `element` won't be transformed to what you mean.

Comment: I thought element is generating the fieldname. if I am wrong, please let me know how to render the form field using the element name.

Comment: I don't know bro, just for test you could arrange the fields in the form itself so to `for field in form` follows the right order

Comment: Thats rendering in the order of the field attribute given in form.py. Have u seen admin feildset, regardless of the order of field attribute, its following the order of the fieldset. So I am not doing anything wrong, thats just my project requirement.

Comment: yes I see admin-fieldsets and also I have done some changes to some of them to re-arrange it. but what you want to do won't work that way(by that code I mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for name in fieldnames %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.name == name %}
            {{ field }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank u soo much.. looks simple but I was doing it wrong.